# free and paid app signed one keystore

Tags: android, keystore, sign

I was sign 2 apps (free and paid) with one keystore but with different aliases and have the same versionName of free and paid app its 1.0 ofc. So, people who buy paid app cant install this paid app because they have free app on device. When they delete free app - instalation is good. The names of applications are different! Please help me understand what wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An app is identified as 'unique' only by it's **application ID**.
They can use the same keystore alias, name etc. but as long as the application id is different they are different apps and can be installed next to each other.

A good approach would be to add a suffix to the free version such as 'lite'.

Assuming you have one app project with a 'free' and 'paid' flavour you could configure your build.gradle to use a different application id per flavour:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.awesomeapp"
}

productFlavors {

    free {
        applicationIdSuffix ".lite"
    }

    paid {

    }
}
```

Please see the [documentation on Application ID](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html)

Comment: thanks RobCo, if I right understand you I need to add your code in build.gradle for free app I'm add - free { applicationIdSuffix ".lite"} (and paid without flavour) for paid app - paid { applicationIdSuffix ".pro"} (and free without flavour)?

Comment: You don't *have* to use flavours. The point is that both versions need a unique applicationId. If you are already using flavours, this could be a way to configure that. But if you have two separate projects, you can just change the `applicationId` value to something different for one of them.

Comment: and I havent problems with future upload new version on Google Play?

Comment: sorry but I dont understand what I need to add or  change. I have 2 versions free and paid. In free I need to add to application ID .free or .lite, in paid application ID .paid or .pro? For example applicationId 'com.example.myapp.lite' and  applicationId 'com.example.myapp.pro' and in productFlavors I have nothing.

Comment: Yes the application Ids just have to be **different**. I'm not sure how else to explain it. Maybe I confused you with the productFlavours. If you don't use them or don't know what they are you can just ignore that. If you're still having trouble maybe you can share your build.gradle file(s) to suggest changes.

Comment: For Google Play, if they have a different application id, they are different apps. So they have to be updates separately and can be downloaded separately.

Comment: Yes, I dont use Flavors before! If its not hard please write here example what do you mean? Now my build.gradle (where is applicationID) of paid app like this `android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.app'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"`

Comment: this is build.gradle of free app `android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.anothername.freeapp'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 23
        versionName "1"`

Comment: I think you should be good as-is. Try to install both on the same phone :)

Comment: compiled. next step - uploading to Google Play :) thanks for help RobCo

Comment: Hey RobCo, Google dont give me upload update, reason - `APK package must be named "com.example.app"`. I tried with flavors and change package names but I have already uploaded apps, they have different `applicationId`, they have different aliases from keystore but they have same code and same `AndroidManifest.xml`